# How to prevent software updater from crashing in at 8 AM?

Tags: update-manager

Software updater runs itself exactly at the moment I start important work in the morning. It stops proper work of all other processes as the disk starts working violently. It's not unusual that it leads to locking up of certain more sensitive software.

How do I prevent software updater from taking all the resources of the system and halting all other processes which do not have any access to memory resources while "software updater" prepares itself to run?

Is there any solution how to use a computer without restarting it daily?

Comment: Since when did every update need a restart?

Comment: @Neil wrong command, `upgrade`.

Comment: @Neil and Tim - `update` & `upgrade`? By the way the simples method would be to disable automatic updates

Comment: the output of  `top` when Software updater takes all the resources of the system.